# How to generate trees or other structures over chunks in a 2D Minecraft-like game

Tags: python, pygame, game-development, procedural-generation

I am trying to create a 2D Minecraft-like game, and I am running into a problem. I'm trying to generate trees on top of the terrain. The terrain is generated with simplex noise, and it is split up into 8x8 chunks, the game generates new chunks if necessary every time the player moves. I tried generating trees by randomly choosing a location on top of the terrain, and setting the blocks above it to the blocks I wanted, then I ran into another problem. The trees might go into neighboring chunks. I tried to solve this problem by storing the parts of a tree that are in other chunks in a dictionary, and generating them from the dictionary when the other chunk is generated, but there is another problem. Sometimes the chunk neighboring the chunk that contains most of the tree has already been generated, so I cannot overwrite it when the chunk that has the tree gets generated... I am slightly confused on how to get this to work.

This is the code for generating new chunks, where the parameters x and y are the location of the chunk to generate:

```
def generate_chunk(x, y):
    chunk_data = {}
    for y_pos in range(CHUNK_SIZE):
        for x_pos in range(CHUNK_SIZE):
            block = (x * CHUNK_SIZE + x_pos, y * CHUNK_SIZE + y_pos)
            block_name = ""
            height = int(noise.noise2d(block[0]*0.1, 0)*5)
            if block[1] == 5-height:
                block_name = "grass_block"
            elif 5-height < block[1] < 10-height:
                block_name = "dirt"
            elif block[1] >= 10-height:
                block_name = "stone"
            if block_name != "":
                chunk_data[block] = block_name
    return chunk_data
```

Here is the main loop where the chunks near the player are generated and are temporarily deleted and saved when the player leaves:

```
running = True
while running:
    dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 16
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"2D Minecraft | FPS: {int(clock.get_fps())}")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    rendered_chunks = []
    for y in range(int(HEIGHT/(CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE)+2)):
        for x in range(int(WIDTH/(CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE)+2)):
            chunk = (
                x - 1 + int(round(camera.pos.x / (CHUNK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE))), 
                y - 1 + int(round(camera.pos.y / (CHUNK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE)))
            )
            rendered_chunks.append(chunk)
            if chunk not in chunks:
                chunks[chunk] = Chunk(chunk)
    unrendered_chunks = []
    for y in range(int(HEIGHT/(CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE)+4)):
        for x in range(int(WIDTH/(CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE)+4)):
            chunk = (
                x - 2 + int(round(camera.pos.x / (CHUNK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE))), 
                y - 2 + int(round(camera.pos.y / (CHUNK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE)))
            )
            try: chunks[chunk]
            except: pass
            else:
                if chunk not in rendered_chunks:
                    unrendered_chunks.append(chunk)
    for chunk in unrendered_chunks:
        for block in chunks[chunk].block_data:
            if block in blocks:
                blocks[block].kill()
                del blocks[block]

    camera.update()
    player.update()
    screen.fill((135, 206, 250))
    for chunk in rendered_chunks:
        chunks[chunk].render()
    player.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Here are the Block class and the Chunk class:

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, chunk, pos, name):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        blocks[tuple(pos)] = self
        self.name = name
        self.chunk = chunk
        self.coords = vec(pos)
        self.pos = self.coords * BLOCK_SIZE
        self.image = block_textures[self.name]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos - camera.pos

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)

class Chunk(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.block_data = generate_chunk(pos[0], pos[1])
        for block in self.block_data:
            blocks[block] = Block(self, block, self.block_data[block])

    def render(self):
        if self.pos in rendered_chunks:
            for block in self.block_data:
                try: blocks[block]
                except:
                    blocks[block] = Block(self, block, self.block_data[block])
                blocks[block].update()
                blocks[block].draw(screen)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (self.pos[0]*CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE-camera.pos[0], self.pos[1]*CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE-camera.pos[1], CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE), width=1)
```

The minimal reproducible code, I think all the information needed would be above but just in case you need the rest:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import *
from math import *
import json
import os
import opensimplex

FPS = 60
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1200, 600
SCR_DIM = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
GRAVITY = 0.5
SLIDE = 0.3
TERMINAL_VEL = 24
BLOCK_SIZE = 64
CHUNK_SIZE = 8
SEED = randint(-2147483648, 2147483647)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.display.set_caption("2D Minecraft")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
mixer = pygame.mixer.init()
vec = pygame.math.Vector2
noise = opensimplex.OpenSimplex(seed=SEED)
seed(SEED)

block_textures = {}
for img in os.listdir("res/textures/blocks/"):
    block_textures[img[:-4]] = pygame.image.load("res/textures/blocks/"+img).convert_alpha()
for image in block_textures:
    block_textures[image] = pygame.transform.scale(block_textures[image], (BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))

def intv(vector):
    return vec(int(vector.x), int(vector.y))

def inttup(tup):
    return (int(tup[0]), int(tup[1]))

def block_collide(ax, ay, width, height, b):
    a_rect = pygame.Rect(ax-camera.pos.x, ay-camera.pos.y, width, height)
    b_rect = pygame.Rect(b.pos.x-camera.pos.x, b.pos.y-camera.pos.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE)
    if a_rect.colliderect(b_rect):
        return True
    return False

class Camera(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.pos = self.master.size / 2
        self.pos = self.master.pos - self.pos - vec(SCR_DIM) / 2 + self.master.size / 2

    def update(self):
        tick_offset = self.master.pos - self.pos - vec(SCR_DIM) / 2 + self.master.size / 2
        if -1 < tick_offset.x < 1:
            tick_offset.x = 0
        if -1 < tick_offset.y < 1:
            tick_offset.y = 0
        self.pos += tick_offset / 10

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.size = vec(0.225*BLOCK_SIZE, 1.8*BLOCK_SIZE)
        self.width, self.height = self.size.x, self.size.y
        self.start_pos = vec(0, 3) * BLOCK_SIZE
        self.pos = vec(self.start_pos)
        self.coords = self.pos // BLOCK_SIZE
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.max_speed = 5.306
        self.jumping_max_speed = 6.6
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0, 0.225*BLOCK_SIZE, 1.8*BLOCK_SIZE))
        self.bottom_bar = pygame.Rect((self.rect.x+1, self.rect.bottom), (self.width-2, 1))
        self.on_ground = False

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_a]:
            if self.vel.x > -self.max_speed:
                self.vel.x -= SLIDE
        elif self.vel.x < 0:
            self.vel.x += SLIDE
        if keys[K_d]:
            if self.vel.x < self.max_speed:
                self.vel.x += SLIDE
        elif self.vel.x > 0:
            self.vel.x -= SLIDE
        if keys[K_w] and self.on_ground:
            self.vel.y = -9.2
            self.vel.x *= 1.1
            if self.vel.x > self.jumping_max_speed:
                self.vel.x = self.jumping_max_speed
            elif self.vel.x < -self.jumping_max_speed:
                self.vel.x = -self.jumping_max_speed
        if -SLIDE < self.vel.x < SLIDE:
            self.vel.x = 0

        self.vel.y += GRAVITY
        if self.vel.y > TERMINAL_VEL:
            self.vel.y = TERMINAL_VEL
        self.move()
        self.bottom_bar = pygame.Rect((self.rect.left+1, self.rect.bottom), (self.width-2, 1))
        for block in blocks:
            if self.bottom_bar.colliderect(blocks[block].rect):
                self.on_ground = True
                break
        else:
            self.on_ground = False
        if self.on_ground:
            self.vel.x *= 0.99
        self.coords = self.pos // BLOCK_SIZE
        self.chunk = self.coords // CHUNK_SIZE
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos - camera.pos

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), self.rect)

    def move(self):
        for y in range(4):
            for x in range(3):
                try:
                    block = blocks[(int(self.coords.x-1+x), int(self.coords.y-1+y))]
                except:
                    pass
                else:
                    if self.vel.y < 0:
                        if block_collide(floor(self.pos.x), floor(self.pos.y+self.vel.y), self.width, self.height, block):
                            self.pos.y = floor(block.pos.y + BLOCK_SIZE)
                            self.vel.y = 0
                    elif self.vel.y >= 0:
                        if self.vel.x <= 0:
                            if block_collide(floor(self.pos.x), ceil(self.pos.y+self.vel.y), self.width, self.height, block):
                                self.pos.y = ceil(block.pos.y - self.height)
                                self.vel.y = 0
                        elif self.vel.x > 0:
                            if block_collide(ceil(self.pos.x), ceil(self.pos.y+self.vel.y), self.width, self.height, block):
                                self.pos.y = ceil(block.pos.y - self.height)
                                self.vel.y = 0
                    if self.vel.x < 0:
                        if block_collide(floor(self.pos.x+self.vel.x), floor(self.pos.y), self.width, self.height, block):
                            self.pos.x = floor(block.pos.x + BLOCK_SIZE)
                            self.vel.x = 0
                    elif self.vel.x >= 0:
                        if block_collide(ceil(self.pos.x+self.vel.x), ceil(self.pos.y), self.width, self.height, block):
                            self.pos.x = ceil(block.pos.x - self.width)
                            self.vel.x = 0
        self.pos += self.vel

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, chunk, pos, name):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        blocks[tuple(pos)] = self
        self.name = name
        self.chunk = chunk
        self.coords = vec(pos)
        self.pos = self.coords * BLOCK_SIZE
        self.image = block_textures[self.name]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos - camera.pos

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)

class Chunk(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.block_data = generate_chunk(pos[0], pos[1])
        for block in self.block_data:
            blocks[block] = Block(self, block, self.block_data[block])

    def render(self):
        if self.pos in rendered_chunks:
            for block in self.block_data:
                try: blocks[block]
                except:
                    blocks[block] = Block(self, block, self.block_data[block])
                blocks[block].update()
                blocks[block].draw(screen)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (self.pos[0]*CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE-camera.pos[0], self.pos[1]*CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE-camera.pos[1], CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE), width=1)

def generate_chunk(x, y):
    chunk_data = {}
    for y_pos in range(CHUNK_SIZE):
        for x_pos in range(CHUNK_SIZE):
            block = (x * CHUNK_SIZE + x_pos, y * CHUNK_SIZE + y_pos)
            block_name = ""
            height = int(noise.noise2d(block[0]*0.1, 0)*5)
            if block[1] == 5-height:
                block_name = "grass_block"
            elif 5-height < block[1] < 10-height:
                block_name = "dirt"
            elif block[1] >= 10-height:
                block_name = "stone"
            if block_name != "":
                chunk_data[block] = block_name
    return chunk_data

blocks = {}
chunks = {}
player = Player()
camera = Camera(player)

running = True
while running:
    dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 16
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"2D Minecraft | FPS: {int(clock.get_fps())}")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    rendered_chunks = []
    for y in range(int(HEIGHT/(CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE)+2)):
        for x in range(int(WIDTH/(CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE)+2)):
            chunk = (
                x - 1 + int(round(camera.pos.x / (CHUNK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE))), 
                y - 1 + int(round(camera.pos.y / (CHUNK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE)))
            )
            rendered_chunks.append(chunk)
            if chunk not in chunks:
                chunks[chunk] = Chunk(chunk)
    unrendered_chunks = []
    for y in range(int(HEIGHT/(CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE)+4)):
        for x in range(int(WIDTH/(CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE)+4)):
            chunk = (
                x - 2 + int(round(camera.pos.x / (CHUNK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE))), 
                y - 2 + int(round(camera.pos.y / (CHUNK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE)))
            )
            try: chunks[chunk]
            except: pass
            else:
                if chunk not in rendered_chunks:
                    unrendered_chunks.append(chunk)
    for chunk in unrendered_chunks:
        for block in chunks[chunk].block_data:
            if block in blocks:
                blocks[block].kill()
                del blocks[block]

    camera.update()
    player.update()
    screen.fill((135, 206, 250))
    for chunk in rendered_chunks:
        chunks[chunk].render()
    player.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

(btw the yellow lines are the chunk borders)

Comment: Can you include your attempts to generate Trees?

Comment: Yeah I didn't include the tree generation, they should be generated in the generate_chunk function, I deleted the tree generation part since they don't work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is to realize how big a structure (e.g. a Tree) can be, calculate how many chunks it can span and then check when generating chunk `(x, y)` all chunks around it. This could be done with something like this:

```py
TREE_SHAPE = {
    (0, 0): "oak_log",
    (0, -1): "oak_log",
    (0, -2): "oak_log",
    (0, -3): "oak_log",
    (0, -4): "oak_leaves",

    (1, -4): "oak_leaves",
    (2, -4): "oak_leaves",
    (3, -4): "oak_leaves",

    (-1, -4): "oak_leaves",
    (-2, -4): "oak_leaves",
    (-3, -4): "oak_leaves",
}
MAX_TREE_SIZE = (max(x for x, y in TREE_SHAPE) - min(x for x, y in TREE_SHAPE) + 1,
                 max(y for x, y in TREE_SHAPE) - min(y for x, y in TREE_SHAPE) + 1)

CHUNKS_TO_CHECK = int(ceil(MAX_TREE_SIZE[0] / CHUNK_SIZE)), int(ceil(MAX_TREE_SIZE[1] / CHUNK_SIZE))


def generate_tree(base):
    return {(base[0] + offset[0], base[1] + offset[1]): block for offset, block in TREE_SHAPE.items()}

# Replace everything above with however you want to generate Trees.
# It might be worth factoring that out into a StructureGenerator class.


def get_trees(x, y):
    out = []
    seed(SEED + x * CHUNK_SIZE + y)  # Make sure this function always produces the same output
    for _ in range(CHUNK_SIZE // 8):  # At most one Tree attempt per 4 blocks
        block_x = x * CHUNK_SIZE + randrange(0, CHUNK_SIZE)
        grass_y = int(5 - noise.noise2d(block_x * 0.1, 0) * 5)  # Same as in generate_chunk
        if not 0 <= grass_y - y * CHUNK_SIZE < CHUNK_SIZE:  # Tree spot not in this chunk
            continue
        out.append(generate_tree((block_x, grass_y)))
    return out


def generate_chunk(x, y):
    chunk_data = {}
    # ... Your old code
    for ox in range(-CHUNKS_TO_CHECK[0], CHUNKS_TO_CHECK[0] + 1):
        for oy in range(-CHUNKS_TO_CHECK[1], CHUNKS_TO_CHECK[1] + 1):
            # For each Chunk around us (and ourself), check which trees there are.
            trees = get_trees(x + ox, y + oy)
            for tree in trees:
                for block, block_name in tree.items():
                    if 0<=block[0]-x*CHUNK_SIZE<CHUNK_SIZE and 0<=block[0]-x*CHUNK_SIZE<CHUNK_SIZE:
                        # This block is in this chunk
                        chunk_data[block] = block_name
    return chunk_data
```

Comment: Sometimes the bottom block of a tree generate into the ground tho, is there a fix to that?

Comment: @AndrewDaNub I would suggest doing a decent refactoring of my code anyway. This is just to give you the idea. I would assume that the problem is with how I calculate `grass_y`. That has to be exactly the `block[1]` value of the block that becomes `grass` in `generate_chunk`.